# VBA editor putting in a space

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use a VBA line:

```
Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("A1")
```

But whenever I save or Run it, the editor puts in a space, like this:

```
Worksheets("Sheet6).Range ("A1")
```

Then it won't run, I think because of the space that **it** added.

Or is it dumb user error?

Comment: Oh (he said abashedly). I guess what I intended was a .Select. Thanks for your tolerance towards one new to OOP.

Comment: @pnuts: No I haven't, I am afraid... Been pretty busy with projects :P Anything worth noting?

Comment: @pnuts: Will Do. Maybe when I wake up. It is 3:30AM and I am contemplating whether I should go to sleep or play another game of FarCry :D

Answer (score 4):

Yes that happens because you are doing nothing with it.

```
Sub Sample()
    Worksheets("Sheet6").Range ("A1")
End Sub
```

Either read from it

```
Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

or write to it

```
Sub Sample()
    Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("A1").Value = "Blah Blah"
End Sub
```

or perform some action...

```
Sub Sample()
    With Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("A1")
        '~~> Do something
    End With
End Sub
```